# Can ATC provide vectors and separation service to and between IFR aircraft in areas where radar coverage does not exist using ADS-B only?

Tags: air-traffic-control, faa, ads-b, ifr-navigation

In the U.S., can ATC provide vectors and separation service to and between IFR aircraft in areas where radar coverage does not exist using ADS-B *only*?

If so, are the separation standards the same as if the IFR aircraft were being provided *radar* vectors and separation service in an area where radar coverage does exist?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Yes. In the United States, ADS-B may be used as the sole surveillance source for the provision of ATC services (including IFR-IFR separation) provided that the automation system ("radar scope") is designed to use it. There are no differences between ADS-B sole-source separation standards and SSR separation standards.

[JO 7210.3 3–6–2 ATC Surveillance Source Use](https://www.faa.gov/air_traffic/publications/atpubs/foa_html/chap3_section_6.html#%24paragraph3-6-2):

> **a.** Surveillance sources that are approved for ATC use are Primary Radar, Secondary Radar, **ADS-B** and WAM. Approved ATC Surveillance Sources may be used for:
>
> **2.** Vectoring aircraft to provide separation and radar navigation.

[JO 7110.65 5–1–2 ATC Surveillance Source Use](https://www.faa.gov/air_traffic/publications/atpubs/atc_html/chap5_section_1.html#aaI46JACK):

> **a.** Secondary radar may be used as the sole display source as follows:
>
> 1. In Class A airspace.
> 2. Outside Class A airspace, or where mix of Class A airspace/non-Class A airspace exists, only when:
>    **(a)** Additional coverage is provided by secondary radar beyond that of the primary radar, or
>    **(b)** The primary radar is temporarily unusable or out of service. Advise pilots when these conditions exist, or
>    **(c)** A secondary radar system is the only source of radar data for the area of service. *TERMINAL.* Advise pilots when these conditions exist.
>
> **b.** *TERMINAL.* Do not use secondary radar only to conduct surveillance (ASR) final approaches unless an emergency exists and the pilot concurs.
> **c.** **All procedures and requirements** relating to ATC services using secondary radar targets **apply to ATC services** provided to **targets derived from ADS-B** and WAM.

[JO 7110.65 5–5–4 Minima](https://www.faa.gov/air_traffic/publications/atpubs/atc_html/chap5_section_5.html#PiK190JACK):

> **b.** *TERMINAL.*
> **4.** ADS-B may be integrated as an additional surveillance source when operating in FUSION mode. **The display of ADS-B targets is permitted and does not require radar reinforcement.**
> **5.** The use of ADS-B only information may be used to support all radar requirements associated with any published instrument procedure that is annotated “Radar Required”.
>
> **d.** ERAM.
> **3.** Up to and including FL 230 where all the following conditions are met – *3 miles:*
> **(b)** The preferred sensor **and/or ADS-B** is providing reliable targets.

Comment: When using lateral separation standards ssr beacon only slashes are measured beacon end from beacon end, 3 or 5 miles, depending on distance from the antenna (i.e., what antenna) . How do you determine distance from "antenna" using ADS B? Also, do the slashes displayed with ADS-B only look the same as with standard ssr beacon slashes so you can determine the distance between two aircraft? –

Comment: In STARS the only sensor which uses ADS-B is the Fusion sensor which shows dots, not slashes; separation is based off the centers of the dots (.65 5–5–2**d**). Antenna distance is determined by distance to the ADS-B antenna, if that is even directly relevant for the controller, which it isn't for Terminal—the computer tells us if we need 3 or 5 miles (5–5–4**b**1, **b**2). ADS-B is an approved source (5–5–4**b**4, **b**5). I'm not experienced with ERAM but I believe the ADS-B slash is the same as the SSR slash; again, ADS-B is an acceptable source (5–5–4**d**3(b) and the Note below).

Comment: Interesting stuff. Don't recall ever hearing a controller "advise pilots" that only SSR is in use, and I don't really know what I'd make of the info, or do any differently, if I did.

Comment: Also, what is WAM in the above context?

Comment: @RalphJ WIDE AREA MULTILATERATION (WAM)- A distributed surveillance technology which may utilize any combination of signals from Air Traffic Control Radar Beacon System (ATCRBS) (Modes A and C) and Mode S transponders, and ADS-B transmissions. Multiple geographically dispersed ground sensors measure the time-of-arrival of the transponder messages. Aircraft position is determined by joint processing of the time-difference-of-arrival (TDOA) measurements computed between a reference and the ground stations' measured time-of-arrival. --- this is what ADS-B tracking sites call **MLAT**

Answer (score 2):

I am not 100% certain about the USA rules but in Australia which is based on ICAOs rules ADS-B is the same as SSR (Secondary Surveilance Radar) for the purpose of providing surveillance seperation. Additionally, the standards is the same standards used.

The only extra condition for ADS-B is they must be a Class 1 symbol and can not be used during forecast RAIM outage. (Australian `MATS 10.2.1.4` and Australian `MATS 10.2.1.4.1`)

In Australia the majority of the country is covered by ADS-B but only the east coast and areas around Perth have SSR coverage. However a full surveillance service is applied where ever there is either or both SSR covereage and ADS-B coverage.

I doubt that there would be any difference in the USA.

Do not get this confused with `ADS-C` which is not the same as `ADS-B` and has different seperation standards and protocols.